# Customize carousel slide using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, youtube-api

I am trying to play multiple videos using youtube api along with carousel. Here, I want to change the slide according to video. I made sample fiddle

```
 var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XxPzW/138/

In the above fiddle youtube url is hardcoded but in my case I will get URL's for each record. When I click on AUTOPLAY button it will play all videos accordingly. I did few change in **onPlayerStateChange** for playAll videos. When I playAll videos the slide content was not changing. I hope my question is clear.